# Moving DNS hosting for Active site to Route 53 - with G Suite MX TTL of 1 week

Tags: amazon-web-services, mx-record, amazon-route53, dns-hosting, ttl

I am following the steps outlined in [this AWS guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/migrate-dns-domain-in-use.html) to transfer my domain hosting from GoDaddy to AWS. Step 4 requires me to lower TTL for my existing NS Record to avoid downtime if I encounter issues. However, I see I also have MX records for my GSuite email which have a TTL of 1 week. Do I need to worry about lowering these too? From research, I believe that the MX record TTL is irrelevant because as soon as the domain has switched to AWS, requests will query there for the MX records instead of GoDaddy. Can anyone confirm/help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as you create the MX record exactly the same in Route53 as it currently is in GoDaddy you don't need to change its TTL. Likewise with all the other records - A, CNAME, etc.

Only NS records TTL matter when switching DNS providers, create all the other records the same as they are now.

Comment: I'm a newb so can't upvote, but thanks for the quick response @MLu